Conceptual understanding: Specifying lifetimes for singular object owning references to its own data
I am still a bit newer to rust and have been getting some practice through Advent of code problems.
I am curious if anyone would be able to explain to my why the borrow checker is dislikes the following code.
A minimal reproducible example would be as follows:
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Foo<'a, 'b: 'a> {
    x: Vec<Thing<'b>>,
    y: Vec<&'a Thing<'b>>,
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Thing<'b> {
    phantom: PhantomData<&'b Thing<'b>>,
}

impl<'a, 'b> Foo<'a, 'b> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let thing: Thing = Default::default();
        let x: Vec<Thing> = vec![thing];
        let mut foo = Foo { x, y: vec![] };
        foo.y.push(&foo.x[0]);
        foo
    }
}

The overall data structure Foo contains two vectors, one containing a Vec of an empty struct Thing and another Vec containing references to those Thing structs.
I have written the lifetimes such that all data contained in Foo should exist for as long as Foo does, and more specifically the lifetime of a "Thing" ('b) is always longer than &'a Thing, however the above code does not compile as it states that:
move out of `foo` occurs here (last line)
returning this value requires that `foo.x` is borrowed for `'a`
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local data `foo.x`
...
returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

I suppose my question is, is the data actually owned by the function given that the reference is pointing to itself?
When I initially wrote this code, I was thinking that the "true" owner of the data would be the Vec<Thing>, which is owned by foo.
I've read that I could fix this by containing the "Thing" in a RC, so that multiple owners for a piece of data could exist. but this feels overly verbose especially for this simple example.

That error isn't the clearest.  In fact, the above code produces two errors: the other being that foo cannot be moved, because its x field is borrowed—and this is fundamentally your problem.  You are trying to create a "self-referential struct", which are problematic in Rust because they necessarily cannot be moved (such as returned from a function) without invalidating any references to themselves that they contain.

The second error is the other side of the same coin: if the borrow is to be valid, it must be valid for lifetime 'a however it is invalidated sooner (by the function's termination/moving of foo in return).  The diagnostic could be clearer in this case: whilst foo.x is "local" whilst the borrow is valid, which is the point the compiler is making, the diagnostic message fails to acknowledge that it would cease to be local after the borrow is invalidated and foo returned.
